# VBA Excel Userform EventHandler for dynamically generated controls not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling, userform

I'm working in Excel 2013, designing a Userform with controls created at run-time. I'm having trouble making a function that will fire on the change event of the dynamically created controls.

The controls are contained in a separate class module that creates them and manages them. I want to add a function that fires on the change event of a combo-box, so I have it declared WithEvents:

```
Private WithEvents myComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
... other controls and variable declarations...
```

I have a function that is passed the frame that I want the controls to be in so that I can create all the components from within the class.

```
Sub initialize(myID As String, myFrame As MSForms.Frame, Left As Double, Top As Double)
    ...
    Set myComboBox = myFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", myID & "_comboBox")
    ...
End Sub
```

This all works, and the ComboBox is created and properties changed though `myComboBox` successfully change how the ComboBox appears.

Because `myComboBox` is declared `WithEvents`, I can find `myComboBox_Change` as an option in the drop-down menus and put it in the module:

```
Private Sub myComboBox_Change()
    MsgBox ("Change Event Fired")
End Sub
```

But this function will not run, and I can't figure out why. A messagebox will not appear when a change is made, and breakpoint put in this function will not stop any code from running. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't check it myself nor sure to remember correctly but ... try "Public WithEvents myComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox" instead of "Private..."

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: Do you have more *than one*? What's the purpose of dynamically assigning the name as `myID & "_comboBox"`?

Comment: There are (potentially) more than one instances of this class in one frame, each with their own combo box. I thought that giving them the same name was either not allowed or would get confusing later on. Would having more than one in a frame cause an issue, even if they were named differently?

Comment: are you adding `myComboBox ` to a collection? Better if you ca post full code for intialize.

Comment: While looking into this, I figured it out. Thank you! `myComboBox` is not directly in a collection. I thought the class the combo box was in was in a collection, but that collection was only declared within a function in the userform. Once I declared the collection of classes containing the combobox for a scope of the entire userform, the event handling worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of some probing questions from cyboashu, I figured out what was wrong. The class containing `myComboBox` was not held by a variable declared for the scope of the entire userform. After the function creating it completed, the components were still in `myFrame`, but the functions to be fired on events were forgotten

Comment: would it work with `Private WithEvents myComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox`?

Comment: Yes, once the class was declared in the right scope, it did not matter whether the component was public or private. Both ways worked.